# Three.js: Why is my scene completely black?

Tags: javascript, three.js, vite

I'm trying to make my first three.js project but the scene stays completely black. I'm using vite as my local server.

This is my js code:

```
import * as THREE from 'three'

//Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene()

//create our sphere
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 64, 64)
const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: "#00ff83",
})
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
scene.add(mesh);

//light
const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100)
light.position.set = (0, 10, 10)
scene.add(light)

//Camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 800 / 600)
camera.position.z = 20
scene.add(camera)

//Renderer
const canvas = document.querySelector(".webgl")
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });
renderer.setSize(800, 600)
renderer.render(scene, camera)
```

I added the canvas in my HTML file like this:
`<canvas class="webgl"></canvas>`

Comment: Is ThreeJS correctly installed? Did you run `npm run start`?  Is the `canvas` available at the moment you do `querySelector`? Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

You must put AmbientLight

```
const light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 ); // soft white light
scene.add( light );
```